# Crontab errors running a Python Script

Tags: python, macos

I have the simple test script:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python3
import os
from datetime import date

tday = date.today().strftime('%-m%-d%-y')
dirName = 'Repository' + tday
os.mkdir(dirName)
```

I set the script by chmod x+a test.py

I place this script on my Desktop, and created a crontab to run it:
* 12 * * * ~/Desktop/test.py

the script runs, but errors up as 
'directory already exists' (logged to email).

where have I erred?

Comment: because you have set the cron job at * 12 * * *, your python script will run every minute past 12. The directory will be created the first time but the next time it throw an error. try applying try-except or change the scheduler of your cron

Answer (score 0):

You're running the script every minute from 12:00 to 12:59. The first time it runs, it creates the directory for that day. The next 59 runs get an error because the directory already exists.

You only need it to run once a day, so change the schedule to

```
0 12 * * * ~/Desktop/test.py
```